# How to get email includes exception with stack trace from application insights?

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I am new on application insights but I have been using xamarin insights for awhile. On xamarin Insights whenever an exception occurs, I am getting a detailed information in an email But on application insight, although I set up an alert as shown below

[image]

All I get is a such simple email with a link in it. clicking link doesnt also help as it doesnt route to exception information. Is it possible to get an exception included in the email?

[image]

Comment: I hope they fix this. They might as well just put the exception information in the email so we can immediately start figuring out what went wrong and begin fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the current time, no: The alert you set up is only for a count (rate), the only information that the alert has is that number.  it is only continuously checking for "is x > y send mail"

The alert doesn't know what exception that triggered the alert.

As a workaround, i'd suggest:

1. open the Search blade for that application insights resource
2. create a search that only searches for exceptions in the last 30 minutes (the smallest time range search allows right now?)
3. save that search as a favorite (favorite button in the search blade toolbar)
4. open the favorites blade, select that favorite you just created
5. pin that favorite to your dashboard.

whenever you get the alert, you could then open that pinned favorite search from your dashboard, and see all the exceptions that have happened in the last 30 minutes.